# Rails gem add file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, paperclip

I want to use [paperclip](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip), but it doesn't support CloudFiles. A fork of paperclip adds a `cloud_files.rb` [file](https://github.com/minter/paperclip/blob/master/lib/paperclip/storage/cloud_files.rb) to the `lib/paperclip/storage` directory (this is also where the Amazon S3 file that comes with paperclip is). How would I add this to my rails app?

And is there anyway to do it without having to clone the repo and use `rake install`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this situation, the author of the cloud files fork has actually created a separate gem, `paperclip-cloudfiles`, so you can just use that Gem instead:

```
gem 'paperclip-cloudfiles'
```

However, you can also just point to the git repository instead:

```
gem 'paperclip', :git => "git://github.com/minter/paperclip.git"
```

Then do a `bundle install` and you should have access to the CloudFiles additions.

Comment: I don't want to do this because the `paperclip-cloudfiles` isn't up to date.